# How to add a div class wrapper around ul tag in wordpress sidebar

Tags: html, wordpress, sidebar

I want to add a div wrapper tag around `ul` tag wordpress sidebar.
For default I see my sidebar code like this.

```html
<div id="meta-40" class="widget HTML widget_meta">
    <title>META</title>
    <ul>
        <li>content</li>
        <li>content</li>
    </ul>
<div>
```

And I want something like this:

```html
<div id="meta-40" class="widget HTML widget_meta">
    <title>META</title>
        <div class="THIS IS THE WRAPPER WHAT I WANT">
            <ul>
                <li>content</li>
                <li>content</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div>
```

My PHP code:

```php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Right Sidebar bottom',
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => ' no description',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
 }
```

```php
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar section" id="sidebar">
        <?php if(!function_exists ('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar ('sidebar-1') ) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share your php code here

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just modify your registered sidebar. Note: I did not check if \n works there in  the below code.

```
'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
'after_title' => '</h2>\n <div class="THIS IS THE WRAPPER WHAT I WANT">',
```

Answer (score 1):

do the following two things:

```html
'after_title' => '</h2><div class="THIS IS THE WRAPPER WHAT I WANT">',
after_widget' => '</div></div>',
```

Answer (score 0):

While it would be EASY to use something like jQuery to wrap your child menus, it is NOT good practice to use jQuery for this purpose. Place this in functions.php:

```
class Child_Wrap extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth)
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"custom-sub\"><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth)
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul></div>\n";
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that your menu is being generated in your header, so go to header.php (or whatever file is utilizing the wp_nav_menu function) and look for anything that starts with "wp_nav_menu".

Since I don't have any code to see, I can only guess the arguments that it's using (if any). If it looks EXACTLY like "wp_nav_menu()" with nothing in between the parenthesis, then change it to the following:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('walker' => new Child_Wrap()))
```